# Patch and UCM project

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Recently we have released our product. 
Our team decided to preserve the source code in separate UCM project for patches.

If we create a separate UCM project , no one will use it except for patch. 
So it will be intact. But at the same time if we need some modifications done in patch to another project we should manually migrate contents.

Will creating new project for patches be a best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you had already an UCM project when you released your project, the best practice is to:

- make a baseline on your Integration Stream
- rebase it a a new Stream dedicated for release maintenance (no need to create another UCM project unless your existing project has already so many Stream that a new UCM project would avoid cluttering of Streams in your existing project)

As long as your are talking about patches to the same component, it doesn't matter that you create a new project or a new Stream: you still can deliver from one Stream to another, even across UCM projects.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge. Our team has many streams already that's why they decided to move to new project it seems.